# Will Ubuntu do any damage to my files installed on windows?

Tags: dual-boot

I have one drive on my computer which has windows 7 on it, I wanna try Ubuntu to see what Linux is like but I am worried about my stuff I did on windows.

Comment: If you just want to give a try for Ubuntu on Windows, then down load Wubi from here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer. it will install as an application.

Comment: I know, I am downloading it but I am worried if anything will happen to files

Comment: @user132170 if you are worried you should make a backup before you do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ubuntu windows installer WUBI that will install the ubuntu inside the windows7 and it will not harm to your windows drive , files and any other software. 
visit :- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

and on you tube there are various videos for how to use wubi and install ubuntu.

after installing ubuntu you can easy uninstall from add/remove software of windows7 control panel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try, why not run it on Live CD/USB? You can even add persistence in USB Stick so that you can install some programs!

If you dont know how to do it, its easy. Just checkout the two links. Less risky for newbie!

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Answer (score 0):

Be very cautious while using ubuntu. While loged in to ubuntu you can access Windows root drive (`C drive`), Those system files which were protected while running windows are vulnerable, Dont delete or even brows C drive, except for `C:\users` folder. Rest is totally safe.

Comment: Why should you "not even browse the C drive". This doesn't make sense since most Wubi installs run off `C:` and the virtual disk is mounted off the same drive.

Comment: What i mean was except for `C:\users` whole of the c drive is used by windows to run it self and programs that you install. While in ubuntu you may accidentally delete/rename/move or otherwise modify the file which may prevent windows from functioning in future.

Comment: I think common sense dictates that deleting/renaming/moving files without any knowledge of what they are will lead to problems. I believe your comments could make some people believe that browsing the `C:` drive could lead to problems, and that is IMO misleading.

Comment: Ok, I meant, if you dont know, what you are (exactly) doing, avoid going to c: drive. If you are a pro you can play with any core windows element.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid installing Ubuntu on any drive that has another operating system on it! And you will get no trouble :D. Instead, you have to prepare (or ask for help) a new partition (use hiren's boot cd's partition programs or gparted on Ubuntu Live CD) to install Ubuntu on it! Ubuntu is worth trying.